# Resource not found String resource ID

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I am making an which app which have 2 android project; 1st project is library project and 2nd project is my main project. project-1 is working fine but when I am adding it in my Project-2 as library it is giving me exceptions like this 
**Resource not found String resource ID #0x76000456**

when i checked my string bundle and R.java this string is there.

I have tried clean Project restart my eclipse and my system.

my strings.xml file looks like:-

```
 <string name="pref_loadrecent_id">loadrecent</string>
<string name="pref_loadrecent_defvalue">false</string>

<string name="pref_confirmclose_id">confirmclose</string>
<string name="pref_confirmclose_defvalue">false</string>
```

and I am calling like this:-

```
BooleanPreferenceDefinition LOAD_RECENT = new BooleanPreferenceDefinition(pref_loadrecent_id,
        pref_loadrecent_defvalue);

BooleanPreferenceDefinition CONFIRM_CLOSE = new BooleanPreferenceDefinition(pref_confirmclose_id,
        pref_confirmclose_defvalue);
```

and I am doing static import of R.string like this

```
import static com.ankit.R.string.*;
```

For testing instead of calling from string id i hard code the values of `pref_loadrecent_id` and `pref_loadrecent_defvalue` then it is showing similar exception(with different ID) for `pref_confirmclose_id` and `pref_confirmclose_defvalue`.

Please help me out.

Comment: @Akki I am using getString(resId) in constructor. as follows **MyApp.context.getString(resId);**

Comment: delete gen folder and try to run again

Comment: or try this getResources().getString(R.string.pref_confirmclose_defvalue);

Comment: MyApp is a class which extends Application and contex is a Context variable in that class.

Comment: i have tried all 3 suggestion from you but nothing worked.

Comment: @Akki my project-1 is on following location http://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/

Answer (score 1):

The parameter which you are passing for your answer might not converted into string ...
first convert it into string then pass that string parameter for correct answer..

for example..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edT);

    String str = edittext.getText().toString();

    int n = Integer.parseInt(str);

    int fact = n , i ,e;

    e = n;

    if (n==0)
    fact = 1;

    else

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            fact = fact * (e - 1);
            e = e - 1;

        }


String str1 = String.valueOf(fact);       <-----//Your mistake maybe here.....

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find any Problem in Resource ID then Go To Project-->Clean

And clean your project, **R.java** file will be generated Again.

Comment: Remove import static com.ankit.R.string.*;

Comment: all strings are presents in **R.java**.

Comment: even these strings are present but it is throwing exception. even after cleaning the project also.

Answer (score 0):

Do, fix project properties and clean the project. Close eclipse and restart it again. It will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but to me it looks as if you're importing only `int` not `Strings` with

```
import static com.ankit.R.string.*;
```

And that could be the reason for your exception  **Resource not found String resource ID #...**

Comment: But the same line works when I run lib project as main project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I casted the int value to string value and it was solved

```
String s = String.valueOf([int value]);
```

Comment: No one is having a problem converting. Android isn't recognizing the strings